# Given the input 10, what output is produced by the print(sum)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
the_max = int(input('enter upper:'))
the_sum = 0
extra = 0

for number in range(1,the_max):
    if number % 2 and not number % 3:
        the_sum += number
    else:
        extra += 1
print(the_sum)
```

I thought it would be 14 by summing 2, 4, and 8
Why is the answer 12 according to my book, given an input of 10?
Am I not totally understanding the remainder operation?

Comment: You've got it backwards. The number must be divisible by 3 and not by 2. It sums up 3 + 9 = 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `n % m` gives the remainder, so if it is `0`, `n` is divisible by `m`.

Also, `if x` returns `True` (passes) if `x` is **not** `0` (actually if it has any "truthy" value).

So `if number % 2` will *pass* when `number` is **odd**.

Equally, `if not number % 3` will *pass* when `number` is number *is* divisible by `3`.

In conclusion, only **odd** numbers, **divisible by `3`** will pass in your current code and be added to the variable: `the_sum`.

With `10`, this is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
x x ✓ x x x x x ✓
= 12
```

For clarity, your current `if-statement` is equivalent to:

```
if number % 2 != 0 and number % 3 == 0
```

---

For it to work as you were imagining, you would need to *check if the remainder was `0`*.

Modifying the if-statement to:

```
if number % 2 == 0 and not number % 3 == 0:      #could also do number % 3 != 0
```

which will then sum **even** numbers, **not divisible by `3`**:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
x ✓ x ✓ x x x ✓ x
= 14
```

Comment: It might be clearer to show the equivalent expression `if number % 2 != 0 and number % 3 == 0` for the question as asked.  (I find != much easier to read than `not` added later).

Comment: @MartinBonner Sure

Answer (score 0):

```
if number % 2 and not number % 3:
```

This is true when `number % 2` yields 1 and `number % 3` yields 0

two such numbers in your range are 3 and 9, so the sum is 12